# Handling observable object properties with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-community-toolkit

How do we handle properties that are objects themselves using `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`?

I understand that I can simply use `[ObservableProperty]` attribute with simple properties e.g. data type of `string`, `int`, etc.

How do we handle properties that are `POCO` objects and need to be observable?

Here's an example:

```
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   string title;

   [ObservableProperty]
   decimal price;

   Person author; // How do we handle this property that is a Person object?
}
```

I understand that source generators in `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` will automatically handle creation of `Title` and `Price` public properties. What about `author`?

Do we use `[ObservableProperty]` attribute to make complex properties observable, such as the `author` property in the above example which is a `Person` object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are multiple scenarios:

**The entire Person object gets replaced**

If you only ever replace the entire Person object and don't change its individual properties (you might select a different person from a list) all you need is to decorate the `author` field with the `ObservablePropertyAttribute`.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   string title;

   [ObservableProperty]
   decimal price;

   [ObservableProperty]
   Person author;
}
```

This change will be reflected in the UI:

```cs
Author = anotherPerson;
```

and this one will NOT:

```cs
Author.FirstName = "James";
```

**Individial Person properties get changed**

If you plan to change the persons individial properties, but keep the instance the same, you need to decorate the individual properties of the `Person` object with the `ObservablePropertyAttribute`.

```cs
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string firstName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string lastName;
}

public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   string title;

   [ObservableProperty]
   decimal price;

   public Person Author { get; } = new Person();
}
```

This change will be reflected in the UI:

```cs
Author.FirstName = "James";
```

and this one will NOT:

```cs
Author = anotherPerson;
```

**Or both**

Or do both and get the UI to reflect any changes, be it changing an individual property or the entire object instance.

```cs
public class Person : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string firstName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string lastName;
}

public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{  
   [ObservableProperty]
   string title;

   [ObservableProperty]
   decimal price;

   [ObservableProperty]
   Person author;
}
```

Any of these changes will be reflected in the UI:

```cs
Author = anotherPerson;
Author.FirstName = "James";
```

Comment: While I understand this flow pattern for MVVM, I have `Person` as a Class in my Models folder, meaning it is not associated to `MyViewModel`. With that said, how would I apply something like `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(MyCommand))]` in the `Person` class to react/update in `MyViewModel` as `Person` doesn't get OnPersonChanged() call, only a child property?

Comment: My workaround was adding a TextChanged for each of my properties (entry), Converter from Event to Command (toolkit), then call CanExecuteChanged for the Command in question. Not ideal but this use case is only two properties right now.